# Соединение условий

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Структура базы на картинке ниже. Нужно сделать вывод данных CASE, но вместо ID юриста(lawyer) и ID клиента(client) нужно поставить имена клиента и юриста из двух других связанных таблиц.

Я попробовал для начала вывести все данные 3-х таблиц таким образом:

```
SELECT * FROM cases JOIN client,lawyer ON (client.client_id=cases.client_id) AND (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id)
```

но, как вы поняли, что-то пошло не так. Я никак не могу найти никакого синтаксиса "ON" и потому не знаю как в нем можно обьеденить условие, а как работает JOIN до меня уже несколько суток не доходит, даже после прочтения десятков документаций... Не поможете?

Благодарю за внимание!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `JOIN client,lawyer` вы пытаетесь сразу с двумя таблицами делать. делайте по очереди

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [справке](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)

> able_reference INNER JOIN table_reference join_condition

то есть только один table_reference, в вашем случае два - client,lawyer

Делайте их по очереди:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cases 
JOIN client ON (client.client_id=cases.client_id) 
JOIN lawyer ON (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id)
```

Comment: Отлично, но как вытащить только 2 имени с тех двух дополнительных таблиц? В плане мне нужно их вывести вместе со всеми данными таблицы CASE.

Comment: @Levelleor, ну так и перечислите поля какие хотите: client.name или lawyer.name

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй разделить на 2 left join и сделать разные условия

```
SELECT * FROM cases LEFT JOIN client ON client.client_id=cases.client_id LEFT JOIN lawyer ON lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id
```

Comment: Отлично, но как вытащить только 2 имени с тех двух дополнительных таблиц? В плане мне нужно их вывести вместе со всеми данными таблицы CASE.

Comment: Согласно справки которую вам предоставли в коментарии вы использовали CROSS JOIN а не INNER JOIN
table_reference [CROSS] JOIN table_reference
Всё просто укажите вместо звёздочки соответствующие поля 
`select client.client_full_name as client_name, laywer.laywer_full_name as laywer_name from ...` 
и далее продолжение запроса что выше

Comment: Просто добавьте в секцию select `cases.*`

Comment: Боже, я запямятовал об этом варианте... Но все-же. К чему вы написали про CROSS и INNER JOIN?

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтоп просто вам совет дали и превили ссылку на справку а сами не читали её же )) ...

Comment: Я там был еще вчера, в том то и дело что я ничего вчера не понял и уже сегодня обратился сюда. Я еще нашел один приятный сайт, который все довольно подробно разьяснил, но и он мне не помог. Проблема для меня крылась в 3-х таблицах, вместо двух и в том что мне нужно было вытянуть именно имена вместо 2-х идентификаторов. Я не до конца понимал как все это работает пока вы мне не показали пример. Теперь все отлично понятно, даже удивляюсь как до меня не дошло в одиночестве..

Comment: @Naumov, я читал, читал :-D просто немного додумал, что именно хотел автор :-) но да в пример забыл _INNER_ потому что копировал из поста код :-D