# Группировка данных по строке

Tags: php, sql

Понимаю что задача не из сложных, но я не вижу решения именно моей. Был в документации и еще много где был.

Что есть:

```sql
SELECT lawyer.lawyer_full_name,group_concat(client.client_full_name) 
  FROM client 
  JOIN cases  ON (client.client_id=cases.client_id) 
  JOIN lawyer ON (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id) 
 GROUP BY lawyer.lawyer_full_name
```

Выводит:

```
Группа1Имя1 - Группа2Имя1,Группа2Имя2,Группа2Имя2
Группа1Имя2 - Группа2Имя2
```

А должно выводить:

```
Группа1Имя1 - Группа2Имя1,Группа2Имя2
Группа1Имя2 - Группа2Имя2
```

Пробовал вариант с `GROUP BY lawyer.lawyer_full_name,client.client_full_name`, но тогда выводит все данные в столбик. Не подскажете?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ключевое слово `distinct` в функции group_concat для подавления дублей

```sql
SELECT lawyer.lawyer_full_name, group_concat(distinct client.client_full_name) 
  FROM client 
  JOIN cases  ON (client.client_id=cases.client_id) 
  JOIN lawyer ON (lawyer.lawyer_id=cases.lawyer_id)
 GROUP BY lawyer.lawyer_full_name
```

Comment: Ох благодарю! Вы спасли меня от еще одного часа поисков!

Comment: @levelleor Дело в том что используешь JOIN а не LEFT JOIN и т.д. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 прочитай в вики там показано как складывает такой join таблицы в секции CROSS JOIN. DISTINCT если смотреть на explain http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html в общем довольно тяжёлая операция с точки зрения mysql.

Comment: @Naumov distinct тяжелая для всей таблицы, если она к ней применяется, потому как требуется сортировка. А в данном случае используется distinct у групповой функции, которая и так, хочешь не хочешь просмотрит все значения строк подошедшие под группу и подавит она дубли или оставит - это уже без разницы, там макс. строка 1024 символа, она в памяти отлично все отсортирует, а скорее всего просто проверит при добавлении очередного значения в строку

Comment: @Mike http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472676/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/472677#472677 да я просто предыдущий вопрос его видел, по этому думаю человек запутался просто.

Comment: @Naumov Человек выводит в строчку всех клиентов по адвокатам, если его не интересует 2000 адвокатов, которые так и не нашли ни единого клиента, то left join ему абсолютно не нужен. И при наличии условия связи таблиц (а оно присутствует), cross join идентичен inner join, о чем и сказано там же в википедии. P.S. Посмотрел доку на mysql в нем join, inner join и cross join эквивалентны

Comment: @Mike Я конечно могу ошибаться но разве при left join тогда когда нет даных, результатом будет null, а inner join это прямое соеденение таблицы т.е. если нету он берёт первую строку, но я могу и ошибаться так как не базист я...

Comment: @Naumov left при отсутствии записей в подчиненной таблице выдает строку с колонками из основной и null в полях второй таблицы. inner вообще не выдает строки, если в любой из таблиц не нашлось записей по условию соединения. Так что left ставится исходя из явной задачи показать строки одной таблицы, не смотря на отсутствие данных в другой.